# build.gradle to pom.xml conversion

Tags: maven, gradle

I have following code in build.gradle:

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'javadoc') {  
    from javadoc.destinationDir   
    classifier = 'javadoc'  
}  
task sourceJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'classes') {  
       from sourceSets.main.allSource  
       classifier = 'sources'  
}  
artifacts {  
    archives javadocJar  
    archives sourceJar  
}
```

When I try building pom.xml it only includes the dependencies in it. I want to generate a pom.xml which can execute all these tasks automatically when i do mvn install. These tasks are already defined by maven as it goals. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to call gradle from maven?

Comment: I have a gradle project for which I need to build maven pom.xml

Comment: Corresponding to my gradle project, I need to generate target folder (that depends on pom.xml). So I need to generate pom.xml automatically so that it can perform all the tasks build.gradle is asked to do.